# query for non-existant value in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, missing-data

I am trying to create an access query that will report when someone misses a task, based on the fact that there is no record for that task for a shift.

I have a table that records task completion basic fields are:

```
Date 
Shift 
Task 
Tech
```

when the tech completes a task, a record is created logging the event.

I need to be able to pull a query that identifies when a shift misses a task.

I have tried an unmatched query to no avail using a sample table with shifts as its only data, and even tried adding the task to this table.

so I am looking for some SQL help.

there has to be a way to do this...

Comment: You don't give us enough information. Tell us exactly how you are going to identify that a shift missed a task and you'll get an answer fairly quickly.

Comment: There will be no entry for the shift if they forgot to enter it.

Comment: I'm still confused. Does that mean the `Shift` column will be empty, or is there another table that we need to check?

Comment: if the task was not entered, there would be no record at all... and that is what I am trying to determine.

Comment: We need more information. Give us some sample data and include each table involved, if you can.

Comment: i need more space for this... i put the reqs and table stats on my google drive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1kVkC_z96PTOHdrQnVDMGUwYWc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like

```
SELECT Date, Shift, Task, Tech 
WHERE Shift IS NOT NULL AND Task IS NULL
```

Comment: Like Invent - Animate said though, really need more info to give you the best answer.

Comment: Yes it does. This will identify all the shifts missing tasks, which is what they said they are looking for.

Comment: I'm assuming there's more to this question than we know

Comment: I think so too, hence my first comment saying exactly that @Invent-Animate

Answer (score 0):

If we make the assumption (i know.. that's dangerous) that you have a seperate shift table, and the shift in the list you are looking for is a foreign key. I think you are looking for a shift ID that has no assciated task. You can a use a join and search for null values on your task table.
example:

```
SELECT shifttable.shift, Tasktable.task, tasktable.tech, tasktable.date
FROM shiftTable
LEFT JOIN TaskTable
ON TaskTable.ShiftID = shiftTable.ShiftID
WHERE TaskTable.PrimaryKey IS NULL
```

Given the Data:
Shift Table:

```
ShiftID    Shift
1          Monday
2          Tuesday
3          Wednesday
```

Task Table

```
TaskID   ShiftID  Date    tech    task
1        1        5/15/15 bob     job 1
2        3        5/22/15 Sam     job 4
```

would yeild the results:

```
Shift
Tuesday
```

Comment: 2nd Table:
shift checker:

ID - autonum (primary)
Shift - number (1,2,3)
Complete - Yes

Comment: I tried the query you provided, substituting my table names, and I get a huge list, but its not correct.

I am wondering if my time stamp CDate is the issue - it has caused problems with other query's...

Comment: post the query as you used it.

Comment: tbl_shiftchecker which contains a fragment of the data in the table that   

the users populate  
fields are:  
ID - autonumber - Primary key  
Solution - short text - this is the task name
CDate - date/time - this holds a time stamp for when task was entered /as complete  
Shift - number (1 2 or 3) /Monitoring complete - yes/no - some tasks are not "monitored" per say, and some tasks that are monitored have other things recorded, so this is only checked when the scheduled monitoring is completed.

Comment: are you using "CDate" as a field name?  CDate is a built in function in Access, using it as an actual field name would be a really bad idea. If it is your field name, change it.

Comment: Is your second table named "shift checker"?

Comment: CDate is the field name - for completed date - it didn't ever give me an error or warning when I created it.

Comment: it won't give you an error when you create it, but it's still a reserved word. You should change it.

Comment: SELECT shiftchecker.shift, tbl_shiftchecker.solution, <code>tbl_shiftchecker.ComDate 
FROM shiftchecker LEFT JOIN tbl_shiftchecker ON shiftchecker.shift = tbl_shiftchecker.shift
WHERE (((tbl_shiftchecker.ID) Is Null));

Comment: "where shiftchecker.id is null" not "where tbl_shiftcheker.id is null"

Comment: changed it and it is still blank. question... i am trying to pull data from a record that doesn't exist, since the user didn't enter one... maybe this isn't possible? If there is a record with wrong shift this works just fine, but I need to know when a record is missing... maybe i asked the question incorrectly.

Comment: are ýou sure your missing tasks?  zero records is what you would expect to see if there were no missing records per shift.  can provide sample data?

Comment: I put sample data in document on my google drive you can see it here: 
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1icHn3ANsWqencqmpCvb2mSFAJ_fooIILdnGvm5d8nbM/edit?usp=sharing)